# Can't verify pip installation of google artifacts registry package

Tags: pip

I'm trying to install a package, using pip, that I have already uploaded to the gcloud artifact registry, as suggested in the google documentation: https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/python/manage-packages#install

If I'm understanding the documentation, pip is able to do this after the artifact registry is added to `pip.conf`:

```
[global]
extra-index-url = [ARTIFACT_REGISTRY_REPO_URL]/simple/
```

`pip3 install [PACKAGE_NAME]` gives me:
`Requirement already satisfied: [PACKAGE_NAME] in [WRONG_DIR] (0.0.1)`, where WRONG_DIR is the location of the package *source code.*

Since I'm trying to verify that pip is able to install the package from the remote repository, I don't want it to "know" about the source code. Unfortunately, I don't understand how it's indexing that directory in the first place.

How can I restrict pip's access such that it doesn't see the source code for this package? I want it to install a fresh copy of the package directly from the artifact registry, as (I hope) it would if I were running this on a different machine that did not contain the package source. I have tried temporarily renaming `setup.py` and removing the package files from the local directory, but get the same result.

Apologies for my poor understanding of pip and how it works.

Comment: Use virtual environments.

Answer (score 0):

Verify the installation of a package from the Google Artifact Registry using pip:

1. If the package has previously been installed locally, uninstall it.
2. Delete any lingering copies of the package's files or folders from the local directory.
3. Modify your `pip.conf` file or create a temporary one specific to this installation.

- Set the `[global]` section to include only the `extra-index-url` pointing to your Artifact Registry repository.

4. Utilize pip to install the package.
5. Pip will fetch and install the package directly from the Artifact Registry, ignoring any local copies.

By following these instructions, you can guarantee a clean installation from the remote repository and stop pip from utilizing any local sources or files.

Comment: The local copy that pip had been finding was not from a previous installation; it was the package source code. Trying to uninstall using pip produced an error (and I didn't want to delete the source code anyway). That said, I was able to bypass this problem by fixing some bugs in my virtual environment configuration.